# Cyborg with heart in a box, loses his cyborg arm in gunfight; handsome guy that sleeps in green goo

Tags: story-identification, tv, cyborg

I remember watching a movie or tv-series in the 90's, could be from the 80's too. They're probably on a spaceship, one guy is a cyborg with a human head. He's got his human heart in a box in his cyborg chest. In one scene someone opens this box and the cyborg gasps for air.

In another scene the cyborg is in a gunfight in a warehouse(?), and one of his robotic arms is shot off. He gets a replacement arm that is out of control, erratically moving by itself. In the end they find the arm in the warehouse(?) that was shot off and it is reattached.

Then there's this character: a handsome guy with long hair that I remember stepping out of his sleeping “pod” filled with green goo. I think the pod is a standing circle where the lower part is filled with the goo/slime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alien character "Zylyn" played by Cary-Hiroyuki Takagawa in the 1993 series [Space Rangers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Rangers_(TV_series)) in one episode had to be awakened from some sort of hibernation in a goo-filled chamber.
[image: Takagawa Space Rangers]